# jquery selector i cant select new element add on the fly but work with existed element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why this code is not hiding elements dynamically added to the `html` document:

```
$("p , h1 , h2").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This selection works only with the existing element in the html page, but doesn't work with what I add with after method on the fly.
It seems that any new `p` element or `h1` element that get added in the fly doesn't get any recognition from this selector.

Comment: Tried delegating from `document` `$(document).on("mousedown", "p, h1, h2", fn)` ?

Comment: yes think's it work very good like document get tracking of any new element that get added unlike my previous selector.at least that's what i think happen think's again.

Comment: @kairox Delegation use the fact that most event bubbles through the DOM as mousedown, but not all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delegating `event` from `document`

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "p, h1, h2", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for jQuery 1.7, this is the way to delegate event:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "p , h1 , h2", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

`document` or closest static container.

### -DOC-